# Executable within a library and while using the same library in cabal

Tags: haskell, package, cabal

This is my first try at an open source project, but I still can't get the right way to set up my `.cabal` file.

I have have library, an executable and a (soon to come) test config.
I want to use the library and within the executable, so the both of them can be used when it gets downloaded.

I followed this [guide](https://howistart.org/posts/haskell/1), but I'm still struggling with the cabal-config as I only get it to work while importing everything again.

My current directory

```
- src/
    - Main.hs
    - Format/
          - C.hs
          - Converter.hs
          - Raw.hs
          - RGB565.hs
- tests/...
- dist/...
- UTFTConverter.cabal
```

The executable Main.hs header looks like this.

```
module Main where

import Format.C
import Format.Converter
```

The library files in Format/ look like this.

```
module Format.{filename} where
...
```

This is what the cabal file looks like.

```
name:          UTFTConverter
...
cabal-version: >=1.10

library
exposed-modules:   Format.C
                 , Format.Converter
                 , Format.Raw
                 , Format.RGB565
build-depends:     base        >=4.7  && <4.8
                 , filepath    >=1.3  && <1.4
                 , directory   >=1.2  && <1.3
                 , time        >=1.4  && <1.5
                 , bytestring  >=0.10 && <0.11
                 , JuicyPixels >=3.2  && <3.3
hs-source-dirs:  src
...

executable UTFTConverter
main-is:         Main.hs
build-depends:     base             >=4.7  && <4.8
                 , filepath         >=1.3  && <1.4
                 , directory        >=1.2  && <1.3
                 , time             >=1.4  && <1.5
                 , bytestring       >=0.10 && <0.11
                 , JuicyPixels      >=3.2  && <3.3
               --, UTFTConverter    ==0.1    <-- this does not work
hs-source-dirs:  src
...

test-suite tests:
...
```

Without the comment this error comes up when I `cabal build`.

```
...
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
UTFTConverter ==0.1
...
```

It works right now, but in the tutorial the executable was using the library in the same cabal file.

```
executable bassbull
main-is:             Main.hs
ghc-options:         -rtsopts -O2
build-depends:       base,
                     bassbull,    -- <-- this is the name of the library
                     bytestring,
                     cassava
hs-source-dirs:      src
default-language:    Haskell2010
```

I know this is currently working, but I would rather use it the right way from the start. Is this the "right" way?

Comment: What's the `version:` line at the top of the cabal file for `UTFConverter`? Does it work if you just omit the bounds check for `UTFConverter`?

Comment: @user5402: [`0.1.0.0`](https://github.com/cirquit/UTFTConverter/blob/master/UTFTConverter.cabal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's due to your library version being `0.1.0.0`, not `0.1`. They don't match up exactly, thus cabal doesn't recognize your library as a candidate. Instead, use `0.1.*` or `0.1.0.0` depending on your version policy:

```
executable UTFTConverter
main-is:         Main.hs
build-depends:     base             >=4.7  && <4.8
                 , filepath         >=1.3  && <1.4
                 , directory        >=1.2  && <1.3
                 , time             >=1.4  && <1.5
                 , bytestring       >=0.10 && <0.11
                 , JuicyPixels      >=3.2  && <3.3
                 , UTFTConverter    ==0.1.0.0
hs-source-dirs:  src
```

#### References

- [Cabal User Guide](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#build-information), section "Build Information".